# Angular 2.0 Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-modules

When I try load my angular 2.0 application I get the following error:
(index):21 Error: Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { searchComponent }      from './search.Component'; 
import { landingComponent }     from './landing.Component'; 

export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: searchComponent
},
{
    path: 'search',
    component: searchComponent
}];
export const routedComponents = [searchComponent, landingComponent];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

AppModule

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { landingComponent }              from './landing.Component'; 
import { searchComponent }               from './search.Component'; 
import { routes, routedComponents }      from './app.routing';
import { homeScript }                    from './Services/homeScript';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes
],
declarations: [
    landingComponent,
    searchComponent,
    routedComponents
],
providers: [
    homeScript
],
bootstrap: [landingComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Type script for booting

```
///<reference path="./../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './appModule';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
  .catch(error => console.log('GUY  ' + error));
```

If I remove 'routes' from the imports the landing pages loads but without
  any error. I suspect that the error in in the routing, because if I remove the
  'routes' in the AppModule the landing page loads properly. I have tried many
  changes but I have not been able to identify the cause of the problem.
  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using? why do you need this for?? 
`export const routedComponents = [searchComponent, landingComponent];`.   I am also new to angular2 and I am working on routing. I am using final version of angular2 and I dont initialize the above statement like you did.

Comment: I've the same error when trying to load a module with moduleWithProviders...

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention the most basic info: "@angular/common": "2.0.1",

Comment: also the routing used is :  "@angular/router": "3.0.1",

Comment: The constant is not currently used. Even if I remove it from AppModule I get the same error

Comment: are you using webpack beta 2? If so please be aware that there are some issues involved this topic.

Comment: I am not using webpack beta 2

Answer (score 11):

The problem is you set routedComponents as part of your declarations.
Since this is not a Directive, Component or Pipe you get this exception.
Remove the ***routedComponents*** from the module ***declarations*** array and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove "routes" from import array and add "routing" to that:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
]
```

Answer (score -2):

Be sure that modules are properly defined as `@NgModule` and watch out for the spelling of your classes to make sure they match up.

Please note that this is as of the Final release of Angular 2.

Also see this thread for additional discussion:
[Angular 2 Release "Unexpected value 'ElementRef' imported by the module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808264/angular-2-release-unexpected-value-elementref-imported-by-the-module)